# Tips on deciphering a funky file timestamp format?

Tags: python, timestamp

We have a collection of scientific instruments which have proprietary image analysis software running on a Windows 7/Vista platform. The software keeps a collection of quality-control metrics in binary format. An enterprising programmer wrote a python library to pull and categorize data from these metrics files. I'm using that, but there's one metric of great interest that I'm having trouble deciphering. In the library code:

```
def parse_binary(self):
    bs = self.bs

    # Extraction Metrics (ExtractionMetricsOut.bin)
    # Contains extraction metrics such as fwhm (full width at half maximum) scores and raw intensities
    # Format:
    #   byte 0: file version number (2)
    #   byte 1: length of each record
    #   bytes (N * 38 + 2) - (N *38 + 39): record:
    #     2 bytes: lane number (uint16)
    #     2 bytes: tile number (uint16)
    #     2 bytes: cycle number (uint16)
    #     4 x 4 bytes: fwhm scores (float) for channel [A, C, G, T] respectively 
    #     2 x 4 bytes: intensities (uint16) for channel [A, C, G, T] respectively 
    #---->8 bytes: date/time of CIF creation --> 2 x 4 bytes for date and timestamp 
    #   ...Where N is the record index
        self.apparent_file_version = bs.read('uintle:8')
        self.check_version(self.apparent_file_version)

        recordlen = bs.read('uintle:8')  # length of each record

        for i in range(0,((bs.len) / (recordlen * 8))):  # record length in bits
            #OMITTED: obtain various data
            #...
            # 8 bytes: date/time of CIF creation
            self.data['datetime'].append(bs.read('uintle:32'))
            self.data['timestamp'].append(bs.read('uintle:32'))

self.df = pandas.DataFrame(self.data)
```

In a python console, when I examine the data, the 'datetime' data make no sense at all. But the timestamp data are much more interesting:

"exmets" is a pandas dataframe that contains metrics for the course of eleven days, from June 5 2013 to June 16 2013:

```
>>> len(exmets.data['timestamp'])
226559
>>> len(exmets.data['datetime'])
226559

>>> exmets.data['datetime'][1:10]
[2861233716L, 2934210013L, 2764566050L, 2864234016L, 2767136307L, 2817880381L, 2936700262L, 2820490642L, 2769576551L, 2866944287L]

>>> exmets.data['datetime'][100000:100010]
[4093949428L, 4104309713L, 4090699103L, 4094859519L, 4094289462L, 4098919713L, 4104359713L, 4104359713L, 4132262259L, 4150663099L]
```

Like I said, 'datetime' is pretty weird. But 'timestamp' seems much more regular:

```
    >>>exmets.data['timestamp'][1:10]
[2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L, 2295344086L]

    >>>exmets.data['timestamp'][100000:100010]
[2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L, 2295345531L]

    >>>exmets.data['timestamp'][226549:226559]
[2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L, 2295347466L]
```

So there's a regular progression from start to finish, but if you assume that these numbers mean seconds, there's a difference of `2296347466 - 2295344086 = 3380`, which equates to just under one hour in terms of seconds. To assume these are seconds seems incorrect then, as the machine was generating data for an 11-day span.

Any ideas about how to go about deciphering this?

Comment: Does the app show the timestamps, to give something exact to compare with?

Comment: Did you try to interpret all 8 bytes as double precision floating point, and see if that could be days or seconds?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that library!  :)

**Important Update**

After contacting Illumina, I was informed of two revelations:

1. I was wrong to parse two fields for date and time; it's actually ONE 64-bit signed integer.
2. That 64-bit signed integer is a C# DateTime counting 100-nanosecond increments starting at Gregorian 1 AD (in python, datetime.datetime(1,1,1)).

*Older answer follows*...

You are so close to the answer. Check this out, using your provided numbers:

```
In [59]: 2296347466 - 2295344086 
Out[59]: 1003380

In [65]: 1003380.0 / 24 / 60 / 60
Out[65]: 11.613194444444444
```

In other words, it *is* in seconds!

I still don't quite understand the format of the timestamp, so this isn't a complete answer, but I thought I would at least share what I know so far.

Part of the mystery can be deduced by considering how the sequencers output data to the binary files.

**How the Illumina sequencers output data to binaries**

One important thing to know about the Illumina sequencers is that what appears in the binaries feels, to us silly humans, a bit nonlinear.  It's normal to see information about cycle #2 / tile 1101 appear before cycle #1 / tile 1103 (for example) when you sort by timestamp.

The most likely cause is that the sequencer doesn't continuously pump information to the file, but rather saves up a bunch of stuff in a buffer and writes all of that in one go.

That's matched pretty well by what's seen in the timestamps, i.e. the timestamps seem to indicate when the accumulated data in its buffer was written to disk, not the moment when the tile in question was imaged.

Try this:

```
print len(exmets.df.timestamp.unique())
print len(exmets.df.datetime.unique())
```

You'll see you have far fewer unique timestamps than unique datetimes. Also it's likely that the timestamps have very regular intervals.  We don't do 11-day runs where I work, only 36-hour at most, so the intervals in my data are about 5 seconds apart.  (I'd be interested to know what your data looks like.)

So my best guess is that this timestamp is seconds-since-epoch, except I don't recognize which epoch it might be referencing. My first guess was NTFS (measured in 100-nanoseconds since 01 January 1601 00:00:00 UTC) but that doesn't work out at all.

Comment: This is huge, thank you. I see I got cross-eyed and made a facepalm-worthy error in my original problem description. Thanks for pointing that out! Great job on illuminate!